# IntelliJ shortcut and keyboard layout

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I recently acquired an HP Spectre 13 on which I installed GNU/Linux (Arch Linux). I then installed IntelliJ. Everything seemed fine until I tried the shortcut.

I'm on an AZERTY keyboard. I configured the system layout so that I can enjoy the right layout, i.e when I type the letter "a", I've got an "a", and so on. However, with IntelliJ, when typing text, the recognized keyboard layout is "azerty", but using shortcuts, IntelliJ recognizes a "qwerty" layout.

Example: To select all the text, we do `^A`. But instead, I get a `^Q`, though the letter "a" is recognized as an "a" when I code.

I'm clueless on this one, since for instance `^A` works fine in my web browser. I doubt it may come from the hardware, but who knows.

PS: Whether it's IntelliJ 13 or 14, the problem is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a solution by forcing the keyboard layout with the "setxkb" utility.

```
setxkb fr
```

It seems that doing it through my Desktop Environment (Cinammon) only solves it partially. It was also buggy.

So I decided to move to something more basic such as [awesome](https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/) and [bspwm](https://github.com/windelicato/dotfiles/wiki/bspwm-for-dummies), where things doesn't come magically since you have to configure everything yourself.

Answer (score 20):

Alternatively, make the azerty keyboard layout first in order in system settings.

[Source link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-1675?_ga=2.207707220.773487457.1585053217-2028618509.1560522162&p=IDEA-15858).

And BTW, guess what, the problem still persists in 2020.

UPDATE: As of September 2020 there is a new checkbox to solve this:
(Settings -> Keymap -> Use National layouts for shortcuts)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For me, IntelliJ was using a different keyboard layout on Debian Jessie.

Force IntelliJ to use the French KB layout:

```
setxkbmap fr
```

https://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard